# Where to find all 137,929 named Unicode characters in 12.1 in downloadable format

Tags: database, unicode

I have downloaded [12.1.0](http://www.unicode.org/Public/zipped/12.1.0/) unicode data, and in the file `UnicodeData.txt` there are only 32,841 lines, so only ~30k characters. Wondering where the other 105,088 characters are, I haven't been able to find them. Wondering if they are somewhere in `Unihan.zip`, or if they are somewhere in the `UCD.zip`. I can't seem to find this information [here](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode12.1.0/).

Wondering what files I use to end up with a database of all the named characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@CraigBarnes is correct that UnicodeData.txt contains all the characters.  Here's some proof (Python code):

```
import csv

D = {}

with open('UnicodeData.txt',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f,delimiter=';')
    for line in r:
        # Count all the CJK Ideograph and Hangul Syllable ranges and generate names
        if ('Ideograph' in line[1] or line[1].startswith('<Hangul')) and line[1].endswith('First>'):
            end = next(r)
            for i in range(int(line[0],16),int(end[0],16)+1):
                D[i] = [line[1][1:-8].upper() + '-' + f'{i:04X}'] + line[2:]
        elif line[1][0] == '<':
            continue # skip private use and control characters
        else:
            D[int(line[0],16)] = line[1:] # count everything else as one entry

print(len(D))
```

Output:

```
137929
```

Answer (score 7):

Some of the entries in `UnicodeData.txt` are character **ranges**, as described in the the [technical report](https://unicode.org/reports/tr44/):

> For backward compatibility, ranges in the file `UnicodeData.txt` are specified by entries for the start and end characters of the range, rather than by the form "X..Y". The start character is indicated by a range identifier, followed by a comma and the string "First", in angle brackets. This entry takes the place of a regular character name in field 1 for that line. The end character is indicated on the next line with the same range identifier, followed by a comma and the string "Last", in angle brackets:

```
4E00;<CJK Ideograph, First>;Lo;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
9FEF;<CJK Ideograph, Last>;Lo;0;L;;;;;N;;;;;
```

Or in other words, the number of lines in the `UnicodeData.txt` file isn't the same as the number of characters in the database. Some of the character ranges consist of hundreds or thousands of characters encoded in only 2 lines.

Comment: Not enough detail :/

Comment: I've added a small summary of the quote at the bottom. It'd be helpful to know which details you think are missing...?

Comment: It says there are 137k _named_ characters, I don't see how these could be named if they are in ranges like this.

Comment: Also would like to know if in fact all the remaining 105,088 characters are within these ranges, or if there's still others in some other places.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `UnicodeData.txt` encodes all of the character repertoire, plus some other unprintable ranges like "private use areas" and surrogates. I just quickly adapted a script I use to generate character tables and it seems to specify 246,702 codepoints in total. Most of the actual characters that are specified as ranges are CJK ideographs, which are documented in [UAX38](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr38/) and described by the [UniHan database](https://unicode.org/Public/12.1.0/ucd/Unihan.zip)

Comment: Since the character ranges are mostly CJK ideographs, I don't think they all have "names" per se. Most apps seem to use the name of the range suffixed with the codepoint, e.g. "CJK Ideograph-3401". The description of what the characters mean is in `Unihan_Readings.txt` (in [`Unihan.zip`](https://unicode.org/Public/12.1.0/ucd/Unihan.zip)).

Comment: @Lance Craig is correct.  Using UnicodeData.txt and counting all ideograph ranges and Hangul syllable ranges, skipping control and private use ranges and including everything else, I computed exactly 137,929 entries from the 12.1.0 database.  I'll share the code in an answer (Python).

Comment: Indeed. Like I said elsewhere, the information in UnicodeData.txt for these characters would all be the same, so it would be silly to repeat those lines thousands of times.